# GitLab Artifacts upload to AWS S3 returns "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab, continuous-integration

When GitLab was configured to store Artifacts locally, it was working properly.

**I just changed the setup to use AWS S3 for storage for the Artifacts and am getting the following error:**

```
Uploading artifacts for successful job
Uploading artifacts...
public: found 2 matching files and directories     
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 500 Internal Server Error  id=814552 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=64_Ke6nz
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 500 Internal Server Error  id=814552 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=64_Ke6nz
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 500 Internal Server Error  id=814552 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=64_Ke6nz
FATAL: invalid argument                            
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The change I made in GitLab config `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` is this:

```
## Job Artifacts
gitlab_rails['artifacts_enabled'] = true
####! Job artifacts Object Store
####! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/job_artifacts.html#using-object-storage
gitlab_rails['artifacts_object_store_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['artifacts_object_store_proxy_download'] = false
gitlab_rails['artifacts_object_store_remote_directory'] = "s3-bucket-name"
gitlab_rails['artifacts_object_store_connection'] = {
  'provider' => 'AWS',
  'region' => 'eu-cenral-1',
  'use_iam_profile' => true
}
```

On the GitLab Server, I verified that it can write to the S3 bucket:

```
~# aws sts get-caller-identity 
{    
    "UserId": "AROG5TBHTQJLFXNZZGYMA:i-223a3992f627e7c7d",
    "Account": "111080024111",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::111080024111:assumed-role/my-company-sharedservices-gitlab-instance-profile/i-063a3992f625e5c5d"
}

~# aws s3 cp file.txt s3://gs-shared-services-sharedservices-gitlab-artifacts
upload: ./file.txt to s3://gs-shared-services-sharedservices-gitlab-artifacts/file.txt
```

I also verified in a test GitLab CI/CD pipeline that the GitLab runner can write to the S3 bucket. It writes successfully.

This is a simplified version of the pipeline that generates the above error:

```
pages: 
  script:
    - mkdir public/
    - echo "123" > public/index.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

I checked multiple log locations and nothing related comes up.

Any help is appreciated, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to work around the issue by setting up the single storage connection for all object types (consolidated form), as described in the documentation here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html#configure-a-single-storage-connection-for-all-object-types-consolidated-form

Basically instead of setting up every single object type separately, this allows for a single configuration block, which configures all of the object types.

When setting it up this way in the GitLab Config (/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb) it worked properly.